# File Group Templates in Android Studio for a Flutter project

Tags: android-studio, flutter, freemarker

I need a way to create a group of files/folders in Android Studio according to a predefined template.

All the ingredients seem there in Android Studio, like the template languages Velocity and FreeMarker template language. The location where to put these templates: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates

But for some reason, the templates only show on an Android project with Java or Kotlin, and not when working on a Flutter project.

Does anybody know a way to generate multiple files and folders according to a predefined template in Android Studio while working on a Flutter project?

Comment: Any updates about this?

Comment: You might want to check out mason. I could not find anything that integrates easy with Android Studio. But Mason check all the marks for what I need. https://pub.dev/packages/mason

Answer (score 0):

I created a plugin, which creates a group of files by custom templates from IDEA interface. https://github.com/Louco11/ArchitecturalTemplates